# .. CLOSED .. JNI error 'java_class == null' Android Studio

Tags: android, java-native-interface

**This is closed. New problem will be addressed in a new question.**

See edit for latest problem. I am trying to pass a Vector3 value from my cpp library to my java activity. I am able to do it vice versa, but cannot seem to find a way to go cpp to java. Anyone mine helping me out with this? I am receving this error: undefined reference to 'jni_createjavavm'

```
JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=/usr/lib/java";
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 1;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
/* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
 * pointer in env */
JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, &env, &vm_args);
delete options;
/* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
jclass cls = env->FindClass("MenuActivity");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "Test", "(I)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid);
/* We are done. */
jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
```

Nov 11 2018 @2031 UTC+9 | EDIT: New Problem.. Crashes with `java_class == NULL`.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
//Some Other Code Not Regarding JVM

JNIEnv *env;
vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
jclass cls = env->FindClass("MenuActivity");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "Test", "(I)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid);
return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to create a JVM instead of just using the one that you got in `JNI_OnLoad`?

Comment: This is my first time even performing this.

Comment: In this case, there are two problems with your updatd JNI_OnLoad. **1)** you cannot rely on **MenuActivity** class to be available when your library is loaded. Don't depend on delicate timing that is controlled by the framework that is beyond your control. **2)** You must specify fully qualified name of the class in a call to **FindClass()**, e.g. `env->FindClass("com/example/hellojni/MenuActivity")`. *See the [JniTips](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni#faq-why-didnt-findclass-find-my-class) again for more details*.

Comment: @AlexCohn _"you cannot rely on MenuActivity class to be available when your library is loaded."_ Why would it not be available? The JniTips page even suggest resolving all classes in `JNI_OnLoad`.

Comment: @Michael, you are right. Resolving FindClass from attached thread may not work as expected, and @fadden wisely suggests doing that from JNI_OnLoad as one of alternative workarounds. My concern was more about calling the static `MenuActivity.Test(int)`.

Comment: Another mistake in the updated code is calling **AttachCurrentThread()**. You should use **GetEnv()** instead, see [this example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SimpleJNI/jni/native.cpp#91)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android, there is no `JNI_CreateJavaVM()`. The apps run in JVM which is essential to access system APIs and services.

The callbacks from native code to the Java part of the app use the `JNIEnv *` that must belong to the current thread.

If this runs on a Java thread, the JNIEnv is received as the first parameter by the native method. You can call back to Java from a native thread, too. But then, you must attach the thread to JVM. `AttachCurrentThread()` accepts `JavaVM *` which can be stored as a global in your native code. You can obtain it in `JNI_OnLoad()` or derive it from JNIEnv with [`GetJavaVM()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp23168).

Each native thread that is attached, *must* be detached on termination. The best practice is to use `pthread_key_create()` to define a destructor function that will be called before the thread exits.

You can read more explanations in the Android [JNI tips article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni).

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I have a new problem now, and I would like some assistance if you may. Thank you.

Comment: generally speaking, it's preferrable to open a separate question when a new problem pops up, even if it's a follow up for an accepted answer.

Comment: Good to go. Thanks for your help!